# jquery activate dropdown of select box

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, hyperlink

How can I activate/deactivate dropdown of classic selectbox by clicking to link in jQuery?
I don't need selectbox replacing with jQuery, because it's too slow for huge number of options.
I test everything but without result.

[sample page](http://www.jklir.net/test-selectbox.html)

Comment: It would be interesting to share what you've tested in order to see why it didn't lead to the required result. Remember that the more information you provide about your scenario (accompanied with code of course) the more willing will be the community to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're saying that you want the `<select>` to display its options via javascript, I don't think it can be done cross-browser (or perhaps in any browser).

Is this what you meant?

If so, I think you'll be stuck creating your own, but finding some other way to accommodate the large quantity of options you require.

Comment: Yes, classic <select> with <option>.

Comment: @JKLIR - Please explain exactly what you want to accomplish, since your question is being interpreted a few different ways. Do you want the `<select>` to "pop up" and display its options? Or do you want to just select *one* option without popping up? What exactly do you mean?

Comment: @JKLIR - From your example it appears as though you are trying to *display* or *open* the `<select>` by triggering a `.click()`. Unfortunately, there is no way to do this with a classic select. See my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to enable/disable the dropdown when you click on the link, you could do this way:

```
$('a#link_id').toggle(function(){
  $('#dropdown_id').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
}, function(){
  $('#dropdown_id').removeAttr('disabled');
})
```

Where `link_id` is supposed to be the `id` of the link and `dropdown_id` is supposed to be the `id` of the select box. The `toggle` function will disable the select box on first click on the link and enable it back on second click and so on.

Comment: I think he wants to disable a single `<option>`, but it's only a supposition as the question hasn't been clear enough.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov: Yeah i posted what I have figured out but he needs to clarify that :)

Comment: Right, for single <select> <option> dropdown

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($(this).attr("disabled") == true) {
                if ($.browser.msie) {
                    $containerDivText.attr("disabled", $(this).attr("disabled"));
                    $newUl.attr("disabled", $(this).attr("disabled"));
                    $containerDiv.attr("disabled", $(this).attr("disabled"));
                }
                else {
                    $newUl.remove("li");
                    $containerDivText.unbind("click");                    
                }
            }
```